# Read the IDAT of a PNG file with Python

Tags: python, png

[my PNG 10x10 picture for the test](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Bzv9q.png)

Hi everybody,
I try to make a Python script that reads/writes a PNG file.
I don't need a full option script.
In this test, no compression, no filter, no interlace,
I use a RGB palette and an Alpha palette (Color Type 3) with a 8 Bit Depth.

I simply don't understand the IDAT chunk...
I was expecting a list of index colors like: 
10px Width x 10px Height x 8 Bit Depth -> 100 Bytes of data in the IDAT but instead I have 206 Bytes. (Please correct me if I'm wrong)
And a range of 0 to 66 for the index colors but it's completely out of range.

If someone can explain me how I'm supposed to read this data or what i did wrong, I'll appreciate it.

this is my code (line 50 for the IDAT):

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3
with open("smile.png", 'rb') as f:
    hexData = f.read().hex()

#Init cursor_0
cursor_0 = 0

#check signature (8 bytes)
start = cursor_0
stop = cursor_0+(8*2)
cursor_0 = stop
if hexData[start:stop] != "89504e470d0a1a0a":
    print("signature fail")

#Read each Chunk
read = True
while read:
    #NEW CHUNK

    #read length of the chunk (4 bytes)
    start = cursor_0
    stop = cursor_0+(4*2)
    cursor_0 = stop
    chunkDataLength = int(hexData[start:stop],16)

    #read type of the chunk (4 bytes)
    start = cursor_0
    stop = cursor_0+(4*2)
    cursor_0 = stop
    chunkTypeHex = hexData[start:stop]
    chunkType = bytes.fromhex(hexData[start:stop]).decode()

    #read the data of the chunk (variable)
    start = cursor_0
    stop = cursor_0+(chunkDataLength*2)
    cursor_0 = stop
    chunkDataHex = hexData[start:stop]

    #read the CRC of the chunk (4 bytes)
    start = cursor_0
    stop = cursor_0+(4*2)
    cursor_0 = stop
    chunkCrcHex = hexData[start:stop]

    #Decode

    #Init cursor_1
    cursor_1 = 0

    if chunkType == "IHDR":
        print(chunkType)

        #check the pDataLength
        if chunkDataLength != 13:
            print("unexpected pDataLength: "+ chunkDataLength)

        #Width (4 bytes)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(4*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        width = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop])
        print("Width: "+str(width))

        #Height (4 bytes)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(4*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        height = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop])
        print("Height: "+str(height))

        #Bit Depth (1 byte)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        bitDepth = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop])
        print("Bit Depth: "+str(bitDepth))

        #Color Type (1 byte)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        colorType = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop])
        print("ColorType: "+str(colorType))

        #Compression Method (1 byte)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        compressionMethod = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop])
        print("Compression Method: "+str(compressionMethod))

        #Filter Method (1 byte)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        filterMethod = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop])
        print("Filter Method: "+str(filterMethod))

        #Interlace Method (1 byte)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        interlaceMethod = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop])
        print("Interlace Method: "+str(interlaceMethod))

    elif chunkType == "PLTE":
        print(chunkType)

        print(str(int(chunkDataLength/3)) + " Colors")

        while cursor_1 < chunkDataLength*2:
            #RED (1 byte)
            start = cursor_1
            stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
            cursor_1 = stop
            red = chunkDataHex[start:stop]

            #GREEN (1 byte)
            start = cursor_1
            stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
            cursor_1 = stop
            green = chunkDataHex[start:stop]

            #BLUE (1 byte)
            start = cursor_1
            stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
            cursor_1 = stop
            blue = chunkDataHex[start:stop]

            color = red+green+blue
            #print("Color: "+ color)

    elif chunkType == "tRNS":
        print(chunkType)

        print(str(int(chunkDataLength)) + " Transparent Colors")

        while cursor_1 < chunkDataLength*2:
            #Transparent Color (1 byte)
            start = cursor_1
            stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
            cursor_1 = stop
            transparent = chunkDataHex[start:stop]

            #print("Transparent Color: "+ transparent)

    elif chunkType == "IDAT":
        print(chunkType)

        #>>>1ST TRY
        while cursor_1 < chunkDataLength*bitDepth/8*2:
            start = int(cursor_1)
            stop = int(cursor_1 + bitDepth/8*2)
            cursor_1 = stop
            colorIndex = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop],16)
            print("ColorIndex: "+str(colorIndex))


        #>>>2ND TRY
        #translate Hexadecimal to Binary
        chunkDataBin = bin(int(chunkDataHex,16))
        #print("len(chunkDataBin)/8="+str(len(chunkDataBin)/8))
        #print("chunkDataLength="+str(chunkDataLength))

        #start at 2 for jumping the 0b prefixe
        cursor_1 = 2

        while cursor_1 < chunkDataLength*bitDepth:
            start = cursor_1
            stop = cursor_1 + bitDepth
            cursor_1 = stop
            colorIndex = int(chunkDataBin[start:stop],2)
            #print("ColorIndex: "+str(colorIndex))

    elif chunkType == "IEND":
        print(chunkType)
        #If END OF FILE detected, break the loop
        read = False

    else:
        print("PyPng script can't handle " + chunkType + " chunk type")
```

Answer (score 0):

Ok, my bad...
i think i forgot the zlib compression...
This block look like better, but i sill have 273 pixels insted of 100...

```
   elif chunkType == "IDAT":
        print(chunkType)

        chunkDataBin=zlib.decompress(bytes.fromhex(chunkDataHex))

        while cursor_1 < len(chunkDataBin):         
            colorIndex= chunkDataBin[cursor_1]
            cursor_1 += 1
            print("colorIndex: "+str(colorIndex))
```

So, the data I have are not out of range anymore.
Each line look like begin with a 0 index.

This picture have 16px Width on 16px Height (not 10px Width on 10px Height like I said).

I was still working with a hexadecimal number instead of a decimal one:

```
        #Width (4 octets)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(4*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        width = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop],16)
        print("Width: "+str(width))

        #Height (4 octets)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(4*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        height = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop],16)
        print("Height: "+str(height))

        #Bit Depth (1 octets)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        bitDepth = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop],16)
        print("Bit Depth: "+str(bitDepth))

        #Color Type (1 octets)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        colorType = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop],16)
        print("ColorType: "+str(colorType))

        #Compression Method (1 octets)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        compressionMethod = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop],16)
        print("Compression Method: "+str(compressionMethod))

        #Filter Method (1 octets)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        filterMethod = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop],16)
        print("Filter Method: "+str(filterMethod))

        #Interlace Method (1 octets)
        start = cursor_1
        stop = cursor_1+(1*2)
        cursor_1 = stop
        interlaceMethod = int(chunkDataHex[start:stop],16)
        print("Interlace Method: "+str(interlaceMethod))
```

Answer (score 0):

If you plan to 'manually' extract PNG data, it's a good idea to keep your browser open at the [official specifications](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/). The pixel data of PNG images is compressed, as explained in [10. Compression](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#10Compression). After decompressing, you get a stream of binary data consisting of *height* runs, each one with *filter_type* + *width* × *pixel_data* (where *width* and *height* are straightforward defined in the `IHDR` chunk, and the exact format of  *pixel_data* – bit depth and alpha – needs to be derived from the Colour Type flag in `IHDR`.

So step 1 is to use `zlib` to decompress the binary chunk. After decompressing, you end up with 16 × (1 + 16) = 272 bytes.

The next step is to iterate over the *rows* and apply the [filter method](https://www.w3.org/TR/2003/REC-PNG-20031110/#9Filters) of each row, to (finally!) end up with a list of actual values in the format defined by the Colour Type.

Each of the filter types uses the previously decoded row as input (row number -1 is considered to be all zeroes), on which a function is applied with the new bytes. Fortunately, your sample image only uses Row Filter #0: None, which is the easiest to implement as it only replaces the old value with the new one. For a more complete PNG decoder, you will need to implement all 4 filters.

This leads to the following:

```
elif chunkType == "IDAT":
    print(chunkType)

    chunkDataBin=zlib.decompress(bytes.fromhex(chunkDataHex))
    print (len(chunkDataBin))

    # create the initial (empty) row
    processRow = [0] * width
    for y in range(height):
        rowFilter = chunkDataBin[y*(width+1)]
        print ("Row Filter: %d; pixel data " % rowFilter, end='')
        for x in range(width):
            colorIndex = chunkDataBin[y*(width+1)+1+x]
            # process filters

            # Filter: None
            if rowFilter == 0:
                processRow[x] = colorIndex
            else:
                # raise an error for not implemented filters
                raise ValueError("Filter type %d is not implemented" % rowFilter)
        for x in range(width):
            print("%02X " % processRow[x], end='')
        print ()
```

Processing the `IDAT` chunk as soon as you come across it works for your test file, but according to the specifications, there can be multiple `IDAT` chunks. The proper way to handle this is to keep a global object to which you concatenate all `IDAT` chunks you encounter (they should be consecutive as well). Only after you concatenated all of them into a single stream, you can use `zlib` to decompress this.

Comment: There must be a way to decompress IDAT chunks without loading them all into memory. Otherwise, what would be the benefit of offering the data in the form of multiple chunks? @Jongware: you yourself commented on a question 6 years ago that those who designed the PNG format had reasons for providing this "feature": see [29517059](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29513549/png-what-is-the-benefit-of-using-multiple-idat-chunks#29517059). I'm actually looking for a way to decompress IDAT chunks without loading them all into memory.